# My clicker game won't work

Tags: javascript, html

I started to work on a clicker game in JavaScript, but it's not working.  I used the console to inspect the element to find out why it won't add anything to `money` and I don't think it is showing the variable either because it won't even show a 0.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script>
      function addMoney() {
        var money
        money+1;
        var cash = document.getElementById("showmoney");
        cash.innerHTML=money;
      }
    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>clicker game</title>
  </head>

  <p id="showmoney"></p>
  <body>
    <button id="click" onClick="addMoney">click</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The call to the function should have parenthesis `()` :

```
<button id="click" onClick="addMoney()">
```

Instead of :

```
<button id="click" onClick="addMoney">
```

Also you have to init you variable `money` and to define it in the global scope so it will not return to default value zero on every click :

```
var money=0;
```

Hope this helps.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script>
      var money=0;
      
      function addMoney(){
        money++;
        var cash = document.getElementById("showmoney");
        cash.innerHTML=money;
      }

    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>clicker game</title>
  </head>
  <p id="showmoney">
  </p>
  <body>
    <button id="click" onClick="addMoney()">
      click
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it works better, but whenever i click it doesn't actually show me the money variable it just says undefined

Comment: @Dankbeats have you run this snippet? It works perfectly.